# StageMonitor: Disable Browser Widget

Tags: java, monitoring, stagemonitor

I would like to disable the browser widget in production release.

I would like to define the disabling the browser widget in **stagemonitor.properties**. Is there any java system properties like as "**stagemonitor.browserwidget.activate=false**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out how to disable the browser widget.

Set:

```
stagemonitor.web.widget.enabled=false
```

You can see more information about it [here](https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor/wiki/Configuration-Options#in-browser-widget-enabled).